# some riddles i tried to solve in discrete math Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

ok so here are the questions and my way for solving it... please let me know if im doing it right or am i in the wrong way...

question1:
 in a group there are 20 women and 10 men , we want to create 15 couples from of them:

a. without limits

b.so each couple is only with the same gender

c.so the gender will be different in 10 of the couples.

My answer:

a.${30 \choose 15}$

b.${20 \choose 10}*{10 \choose 5}$

c.no clue..

question 2:

a bank code made of 3 latin letters(A-Z) and 5 digits.

how many options are if:

A.the code begins with 3 different latin letters(A-Z) and then 5 digits that can be same or not the same.

B. letters and digits can be anywhere but all the digits are different and letters can be anything...

My Answer:

A.$(\frac{26!}{23!})*10^5$

B.$(\frac{10!}{5!})*26^3$

guys please help me...

Comment: Question 2 should be a separate question since it is unrelated to the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Ross Millikan's suggestion that you try your first problem for a smaller set, say, $6$ people, here are approaches for the problem:

(a) Let the people be A, B, C, D, E, F.  First, A must have a partner; there are $5$ choices.  This leaves the identical situation for the remaining four people; the first one (whether B or C) must have a partner; there are $3$ choices.  This leaves the identical situation for the remaining two people, for whom there is but one choice.  Thus the total number of pairings is $5 \times 3 \times 1 = 15$.  Can you extrapolate?

(b) Suppose A, B, C, and D are women, and E and F are men.  Then you can use the reasoning from (a) to show that there are $3$ pairings for the women, and of course just $1$ pairing for the men.  There are thus $3 \times 1 = 3$ pairings overall.  Again, can you extrapolate?

(c) Now, the two men must each be paired with a woman.  So we must choose a woman for E ($4$ choices) and one for F ($3$ choices).  By the reasoning in (a), the remaining two women can be paired in $1$ way.  Thus, the total number of pairings is $4 \times 3 \times 1 = 12$.  Once again, can you extrapolate?

Comment: guys please help me i still dont understand how to do and where i was wrong... thank you...

Answer (score 2):

No.  ${30 \choose 15}$ chooses $15$ people out of the $30$.  You need to choose $2$ for the first couple, then $2$ out of the remaining $28$ for the next couple, and so on.  Unfortunately you probably don't care which order the couples are chosen, so divide by the number of ways to order the couples.  Once you get a, your idea to use the same approach for the men and women separately and multiply the answers for b is correct.  For c, line up the men.  Pick $10$ women in order to form the mixed couples.  Then divide the remaining $10$ women into couples like you did in a.

Comment: so its the sum of ${30-2i \choose 2}$ when "i" is from 0 to 15?

Comment: No, it is the product, because once you choose the first pair in $30 \choose 2$ ways you can choose he second in $28 \choose 2$ ways and so on.  Then you have to compensate for the overcount.

Comment: is it ${30 \choose 15}*2^15  $?
Im really bad at this.... and i dont really understand it quite well...
also added another one i tried to solve

Comment: I suggest you try it by hand with six people.  How many ways to form one pair?  Haven done that, how many ways to form another pair?  Then the third pair is specified.  Remember you multiply the values at each step because for each of the choices for the first pair you have that many choices for the second.  We then have to remove the overcount because you could select the pairs in a number of orders.

Comment: Ross thank you for trying but i still dont understand... can you please give me an example? like how to do it with the calculation for example if there where 4 guys and 8 women? so i can understand it better...

Comment: and how i got it we will have$(\frac{30!}{2!*15})$?